# Jooq one to many select using multiset

Tags: java, postgresql, one-to-many, jooq

i have two tables and and corresponding dto classes:

```
   | Records        |       | InnerRecords|
   | name           |       | name        |
   | innerRecordsId |  <--- | id          |
```

i am trying to implement one to many select using code below:

```java
var res = dslContext
.select(Records.RECORDS.ID,
        Records.RECORDS.NAME,
        multiset(DSL.select()
            .from(InnerRecords.INNER_RECORDS)
            .where(InnerRecords.INNER_RECORDS.ID.eq(Records.RECORDS.INNERRECORDID)))
       .convertFrom(r -> r.into(InnerRecordsDto.class))
       .as("innerRecord")
).from(table).fetchInto(RecordsDto.class);
```

But i got exception:

```java
Caused by: org.jooq.exception.MappingException: An error ocurred when mapping record to class test.ent.Records

Caused by: org.jooq.exception.DataTypeException: No Converter found for types org.jooq.Converters$UnknownType and test.ent.InnerRecord
```

what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you post the definition of your DTO classes, of your tables (`CREATE TABLE`), and the full stack trace, please?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to link the tables the fields used need to be of the same data-type, for example `int` or `varchar`. In some RDBMS compatible types will be accepted, in others they must be identical.
You need to check the data-types of **Records.innerRecordsId** and **InnerRecords.id** and then modify one or the other.